# How can I retrieve the current seed of NumPy's random number generator?

Tags: python, numpy, random, random-seed, mersenne-twister

The following imports NumPy and sets the seed.

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(42)
```

However, I'm not interested in setting the seed but more in reading it. `random.get_state()` does not seem to contain the seed. The [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.random.html) doesn't show an obvious answer.

How do I retrieve the current seed used by `numpy.random`, assuming I did not set it manually?

I want to use the current seed to carry over for the next iteration of a process.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by *"use the current seed to carry over for the next iteration of a process"*? Is there a reason why you can't simply use a combination of `np.random.get_state` and `np.random.set_state`, or else pass around an instance of `np.random.RandomState` to keep track of the internal state of the RNG?

Comment: @ali_m If I fixed the seed, I know what seed to use to reproduce the result. However, if I haven't fixed the seed, how can I see what seed is used?

Comment: why did the answer to your question say `The short answer is that you simply can't (at least not in the general case).` however you accepted the answer. Did he manage to answer your question or not? I am confused.

Comment: @CharlieParker I accepted the answer lacking a better alternative. If you have an answer which says it can and how to do it, go ahead and post it. Acceptance marks can be moved.

Comment: why don't your first set a seed by `seed = np.random.randint(0, 100000)`?

Answer (score 111, accepted):

The short answer is that you simply can't (at least not in general).

The [Mersenne Twister](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_Twister) RNG used by numpy has 2<sup>19937</sup>-1 possible internal states, whereas a single 64 bit integer has only 2<sup>64</sup> possible values. It's therefore impossible to map every RNG state to a unique integer seed.

You *can* get and set the internal state of the RNG directly using [`np.random.get_state`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.get_state.html) and [`np.random.set_state`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.set_state.html). The output of `get_state` is a tuple whose second element is a `(624,)` array of 32 bit integers. This array has more than enough bits to represent every possible internal state of the RNG (2<sup>624 * 32</sup> > 2<sup>19937</sup>-1).

The tuple returned by `get_state` can be used much like a seed in order to create reproducible sequences of random numbers. For example:

```
import numpy as np

# randomly initialize the RNG from some platform-dependent source of entropy
np.random.seed(None)

# get the initial state of the RNG
st0 = np.random.get_state()

# draw some random numbers
print(np.random.randint(0, 100, 10))
# [ 8 76 76 33 77 26  3  1 68 21]

# set the state back to what it was originally
np.random.set_state(st0)

# draw again
print(np.random.randint(0, 100, 10))
# [ 8 76 76 33 77 26  3  1 68 21]
```

Comment: why are you saying that you can't `The short answer is that you simply can't (at least not in the general case).` it seems to me that u can from what I read on your answer. I'm confused.

Comment: I understand that the mapping doesn't work. But, if I use the giant tuple returned by numpy I'm all good right? I guess when you said "you can't" I'm not actually sure what you are referring too with respect to the original question and how that mapping thing has anything to do, does that make sense?

Comment: I don't know if anywhere there is a rigorous definition what seed needs to be in any context. If the tuple or any other structure returns you to the same randomness state that you desired, isn't that then a seed? I didn't know seed **had** to be an integer. But your answer seems to work, or is there a caveat except that integer representation that you mentioned?

Comment: Look, I'm not especially interested in debating the definition of "seed". As long as you're happy to call the output of `get_state` a "seed" then the code shown in my answer will work for you. I interpreted the OP's question as  *"what function does the inverse of `np.random.seed`?"*, and this is impossible for the reasons I discussed above.

Comment: I wasn't debating, I'm not interesting in debating. I was genuinely trying to make sure I understood your answer and that there wasn't a weird unexpected caveat later. As far as I can tell it works and your answer makes more sense to me, which is all good (hence my upvote ;) ). Thanks :)

Comment: "impossible to map every RNG state to a unique integer seed." Since python has unlimited-precision integers, the state space of 64-bit integers is irrelevant, and this statement is false.

Comment: @bukzor Numpy's RNG implementation uses C unsigned integers internally which have finite precision. In fact, it actually uses unsigned 32 bit integers, although it's also possible to pass an array containing multiple of these which I wasn't aware of. See [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/random/mtrand/mtrand.pyx#L618).

Comment: @ali_m Then it certainly fits in a python int.

Comment: @bukzor That's a moot point, since the `seed` argument to `RandomState` is [required](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/random/mtrand/mtrand.pyx#L680) to be an integer between 0 and 2**32-1, or an array of such integers. In principle you could generate an array of uint32s by unpacking the bits in a native Python integer, but that's not something that `RandomState` itself supports.

Comment: The direct answer was given by @vestland. The chosen answer must be changed.

Answer (score 38):

*This contribution is intended to serve as a clarification to the right answer from ali_m, and as an important correction to the suggestion from Dong Justin.*

---

These are my findings:

1. After setting the random seed using `np.random.seed(X)` you **can** find it again using `np.random.get_state()[1][0]`.
2. It will, however, be of little use to you.

The output from the following code sections will show you why both statements are correct.

---

**Statement 1 - you can find the random seed using `np.random.get_state()[1][0]`.**

If you set the random seed using `np.random.seed(123)`, you can retrieve the random state as a tuple using `state = np.random.get_state()`. Below is a closer look at `state` (I'm using the Variable explorer in Spyder). I'm using a screenshot since using `print(state)` will flood your console because of the size of the array in the second element of the tuple.

[image]

You can easily see `123` as the first number in the array contained in the second element. And using `seed = np.random.get_state()[1][0]` **will** give you `123`. Perfect? Not quite, because:

**Statement 2 - It will, however, be of little use to you:**

It may not seem so at first though, because you *could* use `np.random.seed(123)`, retrieve the same number with `seed = np.random.get_state()[1][0]`, reset the seed with `np.random.seed(444)`, and then (seemingly) set it back to the `123` scenario with `np.random.seed(seed)`. But then you'd already know what your random seed **was** before, so you wouldn't need to do it that way. The next code section will also show that you **can not** take the first number of any random state using `np.random.get_state()[1][0]` and expect to recreate that exact scenario. Note that you'll most likely have to shut down and restart your kernel *completely* (or call `np.random.seed(None)`) in order to be able to see this.

The following snippet uses `np.random.randint()` to generate 5 random integers between -10 and 10, as well as storing some info about the process:

*Snippet 1*

```
# 1. Imports
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# 2. set random seed
#seedSet = None
seedSet = 123
np.random.seed(seedSet)

# 3. describe random state
state = np.random.get_state()
state5 = np.random.get_state()[1][:5]
seedState = np.random.get_state()[1][0]

# 4. generate random numbers
random = np.random.randint(-10, 10, size = 5)

# 5. organize and present findings
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'seedSet':seedSet, 'seedState':seedState, 'state':state, 'random':random})
print(df)
```

Notice that the column named `seedState` is the same as the first number under `state`. I could have printed it as a stand-alone number, but I wanted to keep it all in the same place. Also notice that, `seedSet = 123`, and `np.random.seed(seedSet)` so far have been commented out. And because no random seed has been set, your numbers will differ from mine. But that is not what is important here, but rather the internal consisteny of your results:

*Output 1:*

```
   random seedSet   seedState       state
0       2    None  1558056443  1558056443
1      -1    None  1558056443  1808451632
2       4    None  1558056443   730968006
3      -4    None  1558056443  3568749506
4      -6    None  1558056443  3809593045
```

In this particular case `seed = np.random.get_state()[1][0]` equals `1558056443`. And following the logic from Dong Justins answer (as well as my own answer prior to this edit), you could set the random seed with `np.random.seed(1558056443)` and obtain the same random state. The next snippet will show that you **can not**:

*Snippet 2*

```
# 1. Imports
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# 2. set random seed
#seedSet = None
seedSet = 1558056443
np.random.seed(seedSet)

# 3. describe random state
#state = np.random.get_state()
state = np.random.get_state()[1][:5]
seedState = np.random.get_state()[1][0]

# 4. generate random numbers
random = np.random.randint(-10, 10, size = 5)

# 5. organize and present findings
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'seedSet':seedSet, 'seedState':seedState, 'state':state, 'random':random})
print(df)
```

*Output 2:*

```
   random     seedSet   seedState       state
0       8  1558056443  1558056443  1558056443
1       3  1558056443  1558056443  1391218083
2       7  1558056443  1558056443  2754892524
3      -8  1558056443  1558056443  1971852777
4       4  1558056443  1558056443  2881604748
```

See the difference? `np.random.get_state()[1][0]` is identical for Output 1 and Output 2, but the rest of the output is not (most importantly the random numbers are not the same). So, as ali_m already has clearly stated:

> It's therefore impossible to map every RNG state to a unique integer seed.

Comment: TL;DR intermediate random states cannot be restored (e.g. a state _after_ generating 5 numbers). Nice writeup.

Comment: Please check the code and output. In snippet 1, `seedSet` should be `None`, and  `state5` should be `state`. The column order is the dataframes disagrees with the outputs. The text says "seed=123" has been commented out...it has not, and in any case is not used. In snippet2, the commented statement should also be removed for clarity (the statement `state = np.random.get_state()` should not be in the code at all).

Comment: Actually I got this in exact reverse; **original random states** (set via `np.random.seed`) cannot be retrieved after generating numbers, but intermediates (_current state_) can.

Answer (score 5):

A simple solution to know the random seed could be to randomly generate one, and then seed the random number generator.  Something like the following:

```py
import numpy as np
seed = int(np.random.rand() * (2**32 - 1))
np.random.seed(seed)
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed to be able to save a random state that had unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Check the first element of the array returned by `np.random.get_state()`, it seems exactly the random seed to me.

Comment: Yes, while it's not explicit, that's most probably how the answer already provided manages to work as it does.

Answer (score 2):

This answer complements important details others missed. First, to rephrase the conclusion:

> **Original random seeds** (set via `np.random.seed`) cannot be retrieved after generating numbers, but *intermediates* (current state) can.

Refer to @vestland's answer; it may, however, mislead: the generated numbers differ not due to inability to map states, but that an *incomplete encoding* is used: `get_state()[1]`. The complete representation includes `pos = get_state()[2]`. To illustrate:

```py
import numpy as np

state0 = np.random.get_state()
rand0  = np.random.randint(0, 10, 1)
state1 = np.random.get_state()
rand1  = np.random.randint(0, 10, 1)

assert all(s0 == s1 for s0, s1 in zip(state0[1], state1[1]))
```

We generated a number, yet `get_state()[1]` remained identical. However:

```py
np.random.set_state(state0)
assert np.random.randint(0, 10, 1) == rand0
```

and likewise for `state1` & `rand1`. Hence, @vestland's numbers differ because when not setting a seed, `pos = 623` - whereas if we use `np.random.seed`, `pos = 624`. Why the inconvenient discrepancy? No clue.

---

In summary on `np.random.seed(s)`:

- `get_state()[1][0]` immediately after setting:  retrieves `s` that exactly recreates the state
- `get_state()[1][0]` after generating numbers: may or may not retrieve `s`, but it will *not* recreate the *current* state (at `get_state()`)
- `get_state()[1][0]` after generating many numbers: will not retrieve `s`. This is because `pos` exhausted its representation.
- `get_state()` at any point: will exactly recreate *that point*.

Lastly, behavior may also differ due to `get_state()[3:]` (and of course `[0]`).

Answer (score 1):

While what the top answer says is generally true, in that it’s not possible in general, it is in fact possible. I would redirect you to this persons blog: https://kamila.akagi.moe/posts/mersenne-twister/

This individual developed a mersenne twister cracking algorithm to recover initial seeds, and provided the details and algorithm in full. I am not the author, and do not understand what the material in full, but anybody interested in doing this should check this out.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.