# Reading a random seed of a jupyter notebook

Tags: python, numpy, jupyter, random-seed

Is there a way to read the "state" of the random number generator in a jupyter notebook?

For example, if I ran a cell where I specify a neural network architecture, and then train it on some data without specifying a seed, is there a way I can then read what seed was used to run this?

Comment: As far as I know you can't, the easiest solution is to set the seed before you train, so that you know the seed. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32172054/how-can-i-retrieve-the-current-seed-of-numpys-random-number-generator) a similar question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can indeed read (and store) the *current* state of the RNG, but this changes every time it is used, i.e. you cannot do what you describe *after* you have run the cell.

Here is an example (since you have tagged the question with`keras`, I assume you are actually interested in the [Numpy RNG](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.random.html), which is the one used in Keras):

```
import numpy as np
current_state = np.random.get_state()

# produce some random numbers:
a = np.random.randn(3)
a
# array([-0.44270351, 1.42933504, 2.11385353])

# Now, restoring the RNG state and producing again 3 random numbers, you get the same result:

np.random.set_state(current_state)
b = np.random.randn(3)
b
# array([-0.44270351, 1.42933504, 2.11385353])
a == b
# array([ True, True, True], dtype=bool)
```