# What is the working range of `numpy.random.seed()`?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, random

In a python console, you have to set the seed at each run if you want to keep the output the same.

```
In[0]: import numpy as np

In[1]: np.random.seed(1); np.random.randint(1, 10, 5)
Out[0]: array([6, 9, 6, 1, 1])

In[2]: np.random.seed(1); np.random.randint(1, 10, 5)
Out[1]: array([6, 9, 6, 1, 1])

In[3]: np.random.randint(1, 10, 5)
Out[2]: array([2, 8, 7, 3, 5]) # Different output if the seed was not set
```

However, when it comes to running code with multiple files, the random functions in one file would be affected by the seed set in another imported module, which may cause some unexpected issues.

Say, I have two files

```
# main.py
from myfunc import *
import numpy as np

myfunc()
print('main.py:', np.random.randint(1, 10, 5))
```

and

```
# myfunc.py
import numpy as np

def myfunc():
    np.random.seed(2019)
    numbers = np.random.randint(1, 10, 5)
    print('myfunc:', numbers)
```

If I run `main` twice, I'll get the same results

```
myfunc.py: [9 3 6 9 7]
main.py: [9 1 1 8 9]
```

and

```
myfunc.py: [9 3 6 9 7]
main.py: [9 1 1 8 9]
```

This implies that the `randint` was seeded even it was not set in the `main.py`. Seeing this, I guess that was because `np.random.seed()` works somewhat globally. And I should use it carefully, particularly when I just want it to work locally.

My solution so far is reset the seed whenever I finish using it. Like

```
np.random.seed(2019)
numbers = np.random.randint(1, 10, 5)
np.random.seed()
```

I am not sure what the working range of `np.random.seed()` is. And is there any other way to avoid the global setting issues?

Comment: You may want to consider something like the context manager example given at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49555991/can-i-create-a-local-numpy-random-seed

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a scope for (numpy) random seeds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50971213/is-there-a-scope-for-numpy-random-seeds)

Comment: @BStadlbauer Yes, it is very relevant, thanks. Especially this line "1) Yes. `moduleA` and `moduleB` uses the same seed. Importing `random` in `moduleA` creates the global `random.Random()` object. **Reimporting it in `moduleB` just gives you the same module** and maintains the originally created `random.Random()` object." It well clears up my confusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using `np.random.seed()` you seed the global [`numpy.random.RandomState`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated). As a side-note, the global (default) `RandomState` can be accessed like this:

```
numpy_default_rng = numpy.random.random.__self__
```

To only locally seed your `RandomState` you can create your own instance of it and use its methods to draw numbers. (see also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52544935/best-way-to-revert-to-a-random-seed-after-temporarily-fixing-it))

E.g.:

```
random_state = numpy.random.RandomState(seed=2)
random_state.randint(10)
```

will always return the same result without seeding other calls to np.random

Comment: I see. But I noticed that although the results will be duplicated due to the global seeding. However, the results vary across the files, see `myfunc.py: [9 3 6 9 7]
main.py: [9 1 1 8 9]`, do they share the same instance?

Comment: They do share the same instance which is seeded after `myfunc()` is called. The result is different as you creating two distinct sets of random numbers, one after another (equivalent to `np.random.randint(1, 10, 10)`). To get the same result, you would have to reseed the generator before calling it in `main.py`

Comment: Additionally, they are two separate files. I was confused why the instantiation in one module would affect another one that imports the module? This sounds so flexible and sort of dangerous. Shouldn't the variables and instances in the two files be in a separate space?

Comment: So in Python imports happen only [once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2029523/how-to-prevent-a-module-from-being-imported-twice) and the default random number generator is presumably a [Singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern), which is created only once on import of `numpy.random`. You could think of it as sort of a global variable, and I guess it was chosen this way to be able to seed all (possibly many) random number generators with one line (so they can easily be seeded for debugging but left normal at regular runtime)

Comment: @BStadlbauer Can I do e.g. `with n.r.RS(seed=2) as r_s: r_s.randint(10)`?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a local instance of [`numpy.random.RandomState`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.RandomState.html#numpy.random.RandomState) to be absolutely sure that the seed is local:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> first_state = np.random.RandomState(seed=1)
>>> first_state.rand()
0.417022004702574
>>> first_state.rand()
0.7203244934421581
>>> second_state = np.random.RandomState(seed=1)
>>> second_state.rand()
0.417022004702574
>>> second_state.rand()
0.7203244934421581
```

Then you can call all the functions that draw numbers from different distributions *on that local object*, like: `state.rand()`, `state.normal()`, `state.uniform()` and so on.