# How can I store and restore random state in numpy.random.generator instances?

Tags: python, numpy

I did a quick search and the only relevant questions I found talk about the old numpy.random interface. I am trying to understand how to use the [new interface](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/index.html). I would like to be able to run some simulation for a given amount of time. Then I want to store the random number generator state information to a file so that I can continue the simulation at a later time.

I have found one way to accomplish this, but it seems to me to be a bad idea since it isn't documented in the API anywhere. I'm wondering if there is a simple way that I have somehow overlooked.

Let's say that I start a simulation with the following code.

```
from numpy.random import Generator, PCG64
rg = Generator(PCG64(12345))
rg.standard_normal(1024)
save_to_file('state.txt', rg.bit_generator.state)
print(rg.standard_normal(8))
```

Here, `save_to_file` saves the dictionary returned by `rg.bit_generator.state` to `state.txt`. Now, if I want to continue processing the simulation where I saved it at a later time, I can do so by using the following.

```
from numpy.random import Generator, PCG64
rg = Generator(PCG64())
rg.bit_generator.state = load_from_file('state.txt')
print(rg.standard_normal(8))
```

This works, the same 8 numbers are printed for me. I figured out how to do this by inspecting the bit_generator object in the python console. I am using Python 3.6.8 and Numpy 1.18.4. The documentation [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/bit_generators/index.html#seeding-and-entropy) and [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.Generator.bit_generator.html#numpy.random.Generator.bit_generator) on the bit_generator object is extremely sparse and doesn't have any suggestions for this common (at least in my work) scenario.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32172054/how-can-i-retrieve-the-current-seed-of-numpys-random-number-generator/49749486#49749486) to a similar question about the older interface seems to suggest that it is quite difficult to obtain this for the Mersenne Twister (MT19937), but I am using the PCG64 algorithm which seems not to have as much internal state. At least based on the success of the code I have provided. Is there a better way to accomplish this? One that is either documented or condoned by the community at large? Something that won't break without being well-documented if I one day decide to update Numpy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accessing the bit generator through `rg` is the same as declaring `pg = PCG64()` and then accessing `pg.state`. There's nothing wrong with accessing via rg.bit_generator. The docs are a bit scarce but the docs for BitGenerator state that accessing BitGenerator.state allows you to get and set the state if you chose BitGenerator.

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/bit_generators/generated/numpy.random.PCG64.state.html?highlight=pcg64

Comment: So, this seems to indicate that what I'm doing is perhaps the correct way to go then?

Comment: Yeah you're just accessing the BitGenerator via your `rg` variable instead of a declared PCG64 variable.You're not accessing any private or hidden variables and the docs point to this being the correct way to do so.