# How to get current random seed of sklearn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

When I use `train_test_splid` as:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test =train_test_split(X, Y, test_size = 0.9)
```

If I do not set specific `random_state`. how to get the current random seed the program use?

Comment: why not set it yourself? something like `random_state = 3`? each time you dont set it yourself it will use different seed. Note that you should set `shuffle` as well. cause according to [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/glossary.html#term-random_state) , randomization might depend on shuffle as well

Comment: Could you explain any reason why not set yourself ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fundamental thing here is the random state. You can generate random states from seeds. But if you do not specify a seed there is no seed, just a random state. Which you can access if you want:

```
sklearn.utils.check_random_state()
```

or

```
np.random.get_state()
```

You could then later pass the random state object to

```
np.random.set_state(state)
```

Also see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32172054/how-can-i-retrieve-the-current-seed-of-numpys-random-number-generator). You really can't get the seed without setting it first in some way.

Answer (score 1):

From their [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/developers/utilities.html)

> If random_state is None or np.random, then a randomly-initialized RandomState object is returned.

You can use [`check_random_state`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.utils.check_random_state.html)

If you need a Random state,you should initialize it by yourself.